# How to put the array (which its elements are entered by the user) as a condition?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void chose_num(int three_num[])
{
    int i;
    do
    { 
       cout<<"Triple Dice"<<endl<<"Choose 3 numbers between 1 and 6: "<<endl;
       for(i=0;i<3;i++)
           cin>>three_num[i];
    } while(three_num[i]<1 || three_num[i]>6);
}

int main()
{ 
    int three_num[3];
    chose_num(three_num);

    return 0;
}
```

What I mean by `while(three_num[i]<1 || three_num[i]>6);` is that every element in the array should be bigger than 1 and less than 6, if not, it loops, what I'm getting is WHATEVER numbers I enter it always loops, should I really for loop in the do while condition so it checks all the elements or is there an easier way?

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `i` after the `for` loop ends?  What value do you expect to see in `three_num[i]` when the `while` expression is evaluated?

Comment: IMHO, you should use curly braces with the `for` loop and check each value after the value is input.

Comment: @0x5453 i added a cout to check and i is 3, so i think it is checking the 4th value in the array which there isn't, and if i put [i-1] it will only get the value before and not every element in the array, the only thing i can think about is check every element. It is possible in that example since its only 3 values but what if it was a bigger array?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way. This is a matter of conceptual code organization. Right now, you have a confusing structure. If I add in the optional braces for the forloop, I think it is more clear.

```cpp
do { 
  cout<<"Triple Dice"<<endl<<"Choose 3 numbers between 1 and 6: "<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<3;i++) {     // NOTE: i used here
    cin>>three_num[i];
  }                      // i is now 3
} while(three_num[i]<1 || three_num[i]>6);  // only checks i=3
```

Note that what you're actually checking in your while condition is whether `three_num[3]` is valid. But `three_num[3]` points the the *fourth* integer in the array, some random byte! This is dangerous and the source of your problem.

Organizationally, you can think of your code as trying to do something like the following.

```cpp
// pseudocode
choose_num(three_num[]):
    print message
    while three_num not valid:
        read in three numbers
```

One solution would be to write an `isValid` function. For example,

```cpp
bool isValid(int three_num[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (three_num[i] < 1 || three_num[i] > 6) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then use this appropriately in the pseudocode above.

Alternatively, you could rearrange your code to look like

```
// pseudocode
choose_num(three_num[]):
    print message
    for i from 0 to 2:
        while num is not valid:
            read in num
        three_num[i] = num
```

In this case, checking whether a number is valid could be a function, or not --- it's very short and simple.

---

There are a couple of other program notes that I put here in case you are interested. These are recommendations or best practices that you can think about as you learn more about the language.

The problem with calling `three_num[3]` when `3` is too large is a problem with bounds-checking. In the standard library, `std::vector::at` does some bounds checking. Or it is common to perform your own bounds checking, to make sure that this sort of problem doesn't happen.

Also, using `std::endl` as in the OP forces stream flushes in a way that you don't need and slightly don't want. And `<iomanip>` isn't used at all.

Comment: thanks, i do understand my mistake by checking only an element of the array, yet i didn't understand how to use the isValid function in the condition of the loop, i'm sorry but i m not that familiar with bools.

Comment: Also consider: `std::all_of`, `std::any_of` or `std::none_of` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of Or the `range` variants if you have C++20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the condition in the wrong place.  You are waiting for the `for` loop to finish in full first, and then you are checking a single value that is out of range of the array.

You need to restructure your loop to perform the check at the point where a value is read in from the user, before moving on to read the next value, eg:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

void chose_num(int three_num[])
{
    bool valid;

    cout << "Triple Dice" << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Choose 3 numbers between 1 and 6: " << endl;
        valid = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            if (cin >> three_num[i]) {
                if (three_num[i] >= 1 && three_num[i] <= 6) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }

            valid = false;
            cout << "Invalid number entered! Try again" << endl;

            break;
        }
    }
    while (!valid);
}

int main()
{ 
    int three_num[3];
    chose_num(three_num);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, break up the responsibilities into smaller functions.  You could have a function that just reads in a value, then have another function that validates the value is in an acceptable range, etc.  For example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int read_num()
{
    int value;

    while (!(cin >> value)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid number entered! Try again: " << endl;
    }

    return value;
}

int read_num_between(int iMin, int iMax)
{
    int value;

    do {
        value = read_num();
        if (value >= iMin && value <= iMax) {
            break;
        }

        cout << "Number must be between " << iMin << " and " << iMax << "! Try again: " << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    return value;
}

void chose_num(int three_num[])
{
    cout << "Triple Dice" << endl << "Choose 3 numbers between 1 and 6" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        three_num[i] = read_num_between(1, 6);
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    int three_num[3];
    chose_num(three_num);

    return 0;
}
```